# JNDI ORACLE PENTAHO CONNECTION

Tags: java, oracle11g, report, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I am unable to make JNDI connection from my pentaho report designer.Can able to connect native JDBC, but need JNDI.I am facing the following error :

Error connecting to database [test] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

javax.naming.NamingException: Invalid data source:'xe'
Invalid data source:'xe'

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

javax.naming.NamingException: Invalid data source:'xe'
Invalid data source:'xe'

```
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:374)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:323)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:285)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:275)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:76)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2455)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:511)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:58)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:234)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:256)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.ConnectionPanel$EditDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(ConnectionPanel.java:162)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:661)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:67)
at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:79)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.database.DataSourceNamingException: 
javax.naming.NamingException: Invalid data source:'xe'
Invalid data source:'xe'

```
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.util.DatabaseUtil.getNamedDataSource(DatabaseUtil.java:48)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.initWithNamedDataSource(Database.java:387)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:413)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:358)
... 119 more
```

Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Invalid data source:'xe'
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.util.DatabaseUtil.getDataSourceFromJndi(DatabaseUtil.java:133)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.util.DatabaseUtil.getNamedDataSource(DatabaseUtil.java:46)
    ... 122 more

JNDI Name : xe

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your JNDI Datasource for the report designer?

[From the Pentaho infocenter](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/report_designer_user_guide/task_jndi_data_source.html):

> Edit the .pentaho/simple-jndi/default.properties file. The .pentaho
>   directory is in the home or user directory of the user account that
>   runs Report Designer. If you have multiple copies of Report Designer
>   installed to multiple user accounts, each default.properties file will
>   have to be edited.

Comment: Yes, i configured it by adding these lines :test1/type=javax.sql.DataSource
test1/driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
test1/url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe @depr001 
test1/user=system
test1/password=john.... it is working for kettle but not for the report deginer.. using 3.8

Comment: The kettle config is in another directory. This one is in the .pentaho directory in your home directory (~/.pentaho in Linux/Mac, C:\Documents and Settings\<Your Username>\.pentaho\ in Windows).
Are you positive you changed the right file?